# How to construct a SQL query to fetch different rows from same table in different columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, row, fetch

Lets say I have a table in ORACLE database like:

```
ACC_ID | ACC_AMT
111    | 10000
111    | 12000
111    | 14000
222    | 25000
222    | 30000
333    | 18000
333    | 27000
333    | 13000
333    | 15000
```

I want to get the output as:

```
ACC_ID_1 | ACC_AMT_1 | ACC_ID_2 | ACC_AMT_2 | ACC_ID_3 | ACC_AMT_3
111      | 10000     | 222      | 25000     | 333      | 18000
111      | 12000     | 222      | 30000     | 333      | 27000
111      | 14000     | null     | null      | 333      | 13000
null     | null      | null     | null      | 333      | 15000
```

I need each different ACC_ID with ACC_AMT in different columns. The table may have other different ACC_ID also, but I will fetch only what I need. What is the best way to do this?

So far I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=111 THEN ACC_ID END) AS ACC_ID_1,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=111 THEN ACC_AMT END) AS ACC_AMT_1,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=222 THEN ACC_ID END) AS ACC_ID_2,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=222 THEN ACC_AMT END) AS ACC_AMT_2,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=333 THEN ACC_ID END) AS ACC_ID_3,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=333 THEN ACC_AMT END) AS ACC_AMT_3
FROM <TABLE_NAME>
```

But I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: How does one make the link between 111 and 222 in your example? Is `111|10000|222|30000` just as valid as `111|10000|222|25000` or is there some implicit logic you have not defined?

Comment: @Sanpopo So far tried SQL have been added into the post. -Thanks.

Comment: @user2401587 - do you have only three possible value for `acc_id` column i.e. 111, 222 and 333?

Comment: @pratikgarg table may have different ACC_ID values, but I want to fetch only what is needed.

Comment: @user2401587 If you want only for these three values then this is possible but if you want the same for all the values of acc_id then this is somthing tricky and for this you need to write PLSQL code.

Comment: @pratikgarg Lets say the table has total 20 different ACC_ID, and I only want to fetch 10 (fixed ACC_ID) out of them. Will it be possible?

Comment: Yes @user2401587 this is possible for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. But I got the answer from: 
http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/187775/178634/

```
with 
    data as  (
      select acc_id, acc_amt,
             dense_rank() over(order by acc_id) rk,
             row_number() over(partition by acc_id order by acc_amt) rn
      from t
    )
  select max(decode(rk, 1, acc_id))  acc_id_1,
         max(decode(rk, 1, acc_amt)) acc_amt_1,
         max(decode(rk, 2, acc_id))  acc_id_2,
         max(decode(rk, 2, acc_amt)) acc_amt_2,
         max(decode(rk, 3, acc_id))  acc_id_3,
         max(decode(rk, 3, acc_amt)) acc_amt_3
  from data
  group by rn
  order by rn
  /
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot clause it may help you, [Link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3ap11_question_id:766825833740)

Comment: I am using Oracle 10, but PIVOT is available only from Oracle 11. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You can make cases in your query but this is somehow a hard coded option....and in your code below SELECT 
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=111 THEN ACC_ID END) AS ACC_ID_1,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=111 THEN ACC_AMT END) AS ACC_AMT_1,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=222 THEN ACC_ID END) AS ACC_ID_2,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=222 THEN ACC_AMT END) AS ACC_AMT_2,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=333 THEN ACC_ID END) AS ACC_ID_3,
(CASE WHEN ACC_ID=333 THEN ACC_AMT END) AS ACC_AMT_3
FROM <TABLE_NAME>
You are make a case WHEN ACC=111 then etc you are writing this line two times how you are assuring sql which line to execute when

Comment: I wrote that condition twice for ACC_ID and ACC_AMT, but that doesn't matter even suppose I want to get only ACC_AMT for different ACC_ID, I will still face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Comment and situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649303/how-to-construct-a-sql-query-to-fetch-different-rows-from-same-table-in-differen?noredirect=1#comment23948307_16649303)

You can try with following query -

```
select table1.acc_id acc_id_1,table1.acc_amt acc_amt_1,
       table2.acc_id acc_id_2,table2.acc_amt acc_amt_2,       
       table3.acc_id acc_id_3,table3.acc_amt acc_amt_3,
       table4.acc_id acc_id_4,table4.acc_amt acc_amt_4,
       table5.acc_id acc_id_5,table5.acc_amt acc_amt_5,
       table6.acc_id acc_id_6,table6.acc_amt acc_amt_6,
       table7.acc_id acc_id_7,table7.acc_amt acc_amt_7,
       table8.acc_id acc_id_8,table8.acc_amt acc_amt_8,
       table9.acc_id acc_id_9,table9.acc_amt acc_amt_9,
       table10.acc_id acc_id_10,table10.acc_amt acc_amt_10
 from 
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '111') table1 
full outer join
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '222') table2 
on table2.rn = table1.rn
full outer join 
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '333') table3 
on table3.rn = table1.rn
full outer join
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '444') table4 
on table4.rn = table1.rn
full outer join
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '555') table5 
on table5.rn = table1.rn
full outer join
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '666') table6 
on table6.rn = table1.rn
full outer join
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '777') table7 
on table7.rn = table1.rn
full outer join
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '888') table8 
on table8.rn = table1.rn
full outer join
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '999') table9 
on table9.rn = table1.rn
full outer join
(select acc_id, acc_amt, rownum rn from <Table_name> where acc_id = '101') table10 
on table10.rn = table1.rn
```

This should give you the output as you required.

Comment: your solution is only working for upto 8-10 JOINS. I need to get 19 different ACC_ID, for which the system is getting hanged when I am trying to JOIN 19 tables. :(
Any other thoughts?

Comment: @user2401587 in your previous requirement you told about 10 acc_id only.
well .. it depends upon your table size. it may hang even in 2 joins also if number of rows present in table is very very large.
As of now this was the only solution came to my mind.. will see if any thing we can do for this.